# CRAN R package check warning: "Unused files in 'inst/doc' which are pointless or misleading"?

Tags: r, cran

The `r-oldrel-windows-ix86+x86_64` machine on the CRAN package checks page reports the following warning for a package I have uploaded.

> checking package vignettes in 'inst/doc' ... WARNING Unused files in
>   'inst/doc' which are pointless or misleading as they will be
>   re-created from the vignettes: xxx.R

Note that `xxx.R` is a key file in my package source, and I can't simply remove it. I've noticed that this warning pops up on the CRAN checks page for a large number of other packages. Does anyone know where the error originates, and if there is anything that can be done about it?

Comment: But `xxx.R` shouldn't be in the directory `inst/doc`, should it? Why isn't it in the subdirectory `R` ?

Comment: Problem solved, thanks. I think this may have been an artifact of using an external package to build mine initially.